# Using keytool from Java code rather than command line

Tags: java, bouncycastle, keytool

I would like to manage CA certs from Java code rather than using the command line `keytool` command. This only needs to work on Windows.

I'm currently working round this by invoking the keytool command itself with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(myKeytoolCommandString)`
but it smells clumsy.

I seems that behind the scenes keytool uses sun.security.tools.KeyTool but this class doesn't appear to be part of the public API and I cant seem to find any legit documentation for it. I have had a quick look at the third-party [BouncyCastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) library but as a newby to cryptography am not sure if is a suitable solution, any in any case would prefer to minimise dependencies.

Grateful for any recommendations.

Comment: This might be useful:  https://code.google.com/p/java-use-examples/source/browse/trunk/src/com/aw/ad/util/InstallCert.java.  Connects to a website to obtain its certificate, downloads certificate and adds it to a new keystore file. Last bit might be useful.

Comment: What operation do you want to do exactly with `keytool`? If you want for example deal with keystores to add a certificates etc. you can do it with ` java.security` classes. Can you share the keytool command that you want to execute?